# Triggering mouseover in Firefox vs Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

I have just started working with JavaScript. I have a search box where when I start typing something, I get a list of results.

By default,the first result is highlighted.

Now there is an event listener which should be triggered onmouseover and change highlighting of the result when I move the mouse from one result to another.

Code which is triggered on mouseover is as follows

```
searchedDOM.on("mouseover click", '[purpose="search"]',  function(event) {
    //highlight this result
});
```

Now, when I start typing something in search box, the mouseover event is generated in Firefox but not in Chrome.

So, in this case, the highlighting of first result is changed to **x**th result (where my cursor was already present) in Firefox. Due to which, it doesn't show the first result as highlighted.

How can avoid this "first" mousover in Firefox?

Comment: You should shate a few more lines around this line. There is probably a closing parenthesis after this line